# 2 consequent while loop c++ weird behaviour

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I've got the following code in a thread - some background: it checks a bool `Binaryrunning` and then lowers or ups audio volume - While the result is what I want it to be, there is some behaviour I don't understand

`maxvol` is 100 and `minvol` is 40 both int's

```
while(threadrunning)
{
    curvol = music.getVolume();

    if(tgtvol!=curvol)
    {
        while(curvol<tgtvol)
        {
            curvol++;
            music.setVolume(curvol);
            std::cout<<"curvol is " << curvol << " tgtvol is " << tgtvol << std::endl;
            usleep(20000);
        }

        while(curvol>tgtvol)
        {
            curvol--;
            music.setVolume(curvol);
            std::cout<<"curvol is " << curvol << " tgtvol is " << tgtvol << std::endl;
            usleep(20000);
        }

        std::cout << "CURVOL IS " <<curvol <<std::endl;
    }

    if(Binaryrunning)
    {
        tgtvol=minvol;
    }
    else
    {
        tgtvol=maxvol;
    }

    usleep(TTWMS*2);
}
```

now, if the `curvol` is lower than the `tgtvol` it outputs:

```
curvol is 98 tgtvol is 100
curvol is 99 tgtvol is 100
curvol is 100 tgtvol is 100
CURVOL IS 100
```

and then stops output - all fine...

if it lowers it outputs:

```
curvol is 41 tgtvol is 40
curvol is 40 tgtvol is 40
CURVOL IS 40
curvol is 40 tgtvol is 40
CURVOL IS 40
```

and so on but it should just output

```
curvol is 40 tgtvol is 40
CURVOL IS 40
```

once and the stop no? I don't get it? I must seem daft but I just don't see it...

can someone clarify this?

Comment: I'm suspicious of code that uses threads but do not use any synchronization.  Usage of `sleep` for synchronization is almost always wrong.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an [mcve]?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, what do you mean by 'amost'? I can't think of **any** case when usage of sleep() for synchronization is right. I can hardly think of a case when usage of sleep for **any purpose** is justified.

Comment: You should output a message *before* you increment or decrement `curvol`, or at least delineate with two different messages which one is being printed.  Right now, it isn't clear which loop is printing those repeated messages.

Comment: @SergeyA -- *I can hardly think of a case* -- Which is why I said "almost" ;)

Comment: I don't think the code you posted could do that. I suspect that while it was sleeping, another thread increased the volume. It would help if you added some more `cout` statements.

Comment: I use the usleep to slow down the volume adjustments so I can hear the change. Is this the correct way then? std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(x)); I'll create a compilable example after trying the last two suggestions